# Convert image data to binary text for vcard

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, vcf-vcard

I need to include an image in a vcard file. The image is supposed to be in binary format. I create the image data as follows:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Pic1"], 1.0);
```

I have unsuccessfully tried encoding using the following 2 methods:

```
vcardString = [vcardString stringByAppendingFormat:@"PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG:%@\n", [imageData base64EncodedString]];
```

AND

```
vcardString = [vcardString stringByAppendingFormat:@"PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG:%@\n", [imageData description]];
```

Any advice on how to get the image data properly encoded to binary would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you get a solution for this issue? I need help on the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

According [to this blog entry I found](http://www.designateonline.com/discussions/comments.php?DiscussionID=5703&page=1) (which points to [this spec](http://www.imc.org/pdi/vcard-21.txt)), it looks like the second form of what you're trying to do should work.

Change your `ENCODING=b` to `ENCODING=BASE64` and see if that makes the difference.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The image is still not recognised when the vcard is imported into address book. I see though in the spec lines longer than 75 chars should be "folded" according to [MIME-DIR], but have no idea what that means.

Comment: @RunLoop It means each line in the file should be 75 characters. To indicate that the next line is a continuation, indent it with a *single space*. Effectively you get 75 characters of content on the first line, followed by a bunch of lines with a space and 74 characters of content. See [vCard validator](https://github.com/l0b0/vCard-module) (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Comment: @l0b0 I eventually figured it out about an hour ago after quite a few hours of struggling. If only I had found your article earlier. Thank you for posting though :)

Answer (score 1):

OS X v10.11 and iOS 9 introduces [CNContactVCardSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContactVCardSerialization_Class/index.html) which greatly simplifies embedding images in a VCard.

Comment: @ Jesper Christensen it is giving null